# How can i save my recording while i press the stop sharing for the first time i record?

Tags: javascript

[image]When I start recording my Screen using navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia() API, I am not able to save it automatically when I press the stop sharing button for the first time I record but it works perfectly and saves my webm file when I record again after the first recording

```
            let start = document.getElementById('start'),
            
            mediaRecorder;

            start.addEventListener('click', async function(){
                let stream = await recordScreen();
                let mimeType = 'video/webm';
                mediaRecorder = createRecorder(stream, mimeType);
                let node = document.createElement("p");
                node.textContent = "Started recording";
                document.body.appendChild(node);
                start.style=NULL;
            })  
          

            async function recordScreen(){
                return await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
                preferCurrentTab:'True',
                systemAudio: "include",
                audio: 'True',

                video: { mediaSource: "tab"}                             
                });

            }

            function createRecorder (stream, mimeType) {
            // the stream data is stored in this array
                let recordedChunks = []; 

                const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

                mediaRecorder.onstop = function(){
                    saveFile(recordedChunks);
                    recordedChunks = [];
                    
                };
                mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
                    if (e.data.size > 0) {
                    recordedChunks.push(e.data);
                    }   
                };
                
                               
                mediaRecorder.start(200); // For every 200ms the stream data will be stored in a separate chunk.
                return mediaRecorder;
               
            }
            
            function saveFile(recordedChunks){
                
                const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
                    type: 'video/webm'
                    });
                    let filename = window.prompt('Enter file name'),
                    downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
                    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    downloadLink.download = `${filename}.webm`;

                    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                    downloadLink.click();
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(blob); // clear from memory
                    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
                    start.style.background="#EB455F";

            }
```

When I press stop sharing it saves my file.